# How I can display a multiline string in bat file

Tags: batch-file

How I can store a multiline string inside a variable batch file?

I mean how to store all the content of text file in only one variable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set NLM=^



set NL=^^^%NLM%%NLM%^%NLM%%NLM%

for /f "delims=" %%i in (file.txt) do set a=!a!!nl!%%i

echo %a%
```

the last echo will display every line of the file, verifying that %a% holds them all.
hope this helps ;)

Comment: lines that start with `;` will be ignored. it can be easily fixed with `for /f delims^=^ eol^= %%L in (";") do set "a=!a!!nlm!%%L"` with delayed expansion, you can directly use `NLM` (there's no need to escape anything)

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this using powershell:-

```
$content = [IO.File]::ReadAllText(".\abc.txt")
```

or you may try like this to display multiline:

```
@echo off
set nl=^& echo.
echo This%nl%is%nl%an%nl%example
```

or to store it in a variable try like this:-

```
for /f "delims=" %%i in (abc.txt) do set "target=!target! %%i"
```

Comment: That doesn't look like batch syntax to me. Windows doesn't think so either. Can you explain

Comment: @AshBurlaczenko:- Thats true. Actually I forgot to write that it was powershell. I have updated my answer. Does that makes it better?